# Is it safe to mention flight numbers in questions?

Tags: discussion

While browsing the questions about short connections, I noticed that few if any gave flight numbers.

From an identify theft perspective (such as someone wanting to steal my flight), is there a risk with specifying your flight number (like "QF1", not your booking number) along with your real name? (Unfortunately my date of birth is fairly easy to google)